# value of select ignore one type of child

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML

```
<p>
        <b>Chapter 3: Industrial Drawings</b>
        <fn>
          <fnn>11</fnn>
          <fnt>
            <p>fnt 1</p>
          </fnt>
        </fn>
        <b>and Designs</b>
      </p>
```

and i'm using the below line, i'm getting the data in `p`

```
<xsl:template match ="p">
<xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::*/text() except descendant::fn"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here i'm trying to get the content of `p` and ignore `fn` node(). But my output currently is

```
Chapter 3: Industrial Drawings11fnt 1and Designs
```

but expected is

```
Chapter 3: Industrial Drawings and Designs
```

here i'm using `descendant-or-self::*/text()` because there might be many cases like below.

```
p/b/text()
p/b/c/text()
p/i/c/text() etc...
```

I want to ignore only `fn` and print the text(). please let me know how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `except` operator is basically set difference, `X except Y` gives you all the nodes that are in set X and not in set Y.  In your case your "X" is a set of text nodes and your "Y" is a set of element nodes, so it won't exclude anything.  If you wanted all descendant text nodes except those that are inside some `fn` you could say

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//text()[not(ancestor::fn)]"/>
```